# Spree not loading images on Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, spree

I'm trying to make images load on **Spree 3.1.0 + Passenger 5.0.30 + Nginx + Capistrano 3.5 + Digital Ocean**, I have followed [Go Rails Tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) and [Spree documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/manual-ubuntu.html#setting-up-nginx) but no luck at the moment.

Weird... Is loading my css files but not loading my image-background

my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name rodeobest.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }


    # if the request is for a static resource, nginx should serve it dir$
    # and add a far future expires header to it, making the browser
    # cache the resource and navigate faster over the website
    location ~ ^/(spree|system|assets)/  {
            root /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/current/public;
            expires max;
            break;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
            root /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/current/public;
    }

}
```

As documentation says, I've changed `location ~ ^/(system|assets)/` to `location ~ ^/(spree|system|assets)/` and restart the server, but as I said, no luck. Any idea? thanks in advance

References:

[Reference 1](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/spree-user/131bpzf633/cant-get-images-working-in-production-system)
[Reference 2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-configure-nginx-with-spree-3-images-not-showing-in-rail-s-production-mode)

Comment: can you show me how you are loading image in background ?

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy. I'm loading images, for example image background with: `background-image: url(rodeobest.jpg)` on sass. In developer tools I get: `iframe.js:249 GET http://138.68.8.255/assets/spree/frontend/rodeo_cover.jpg 404 (Not Found)`   the route for the image is vendor > assets > images > spree > frontend, but neither in the images of the items shown. any idea?